# Phone field behavior

Tags: visualforce

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
<apex:form>
    <apex:pageblock>
        <apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:inputField value="{!account.phone}"/>
             <apex:inputField value="{!account.industry}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

    </apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Question:

When I enter the phone # and tab out of the field, and the phone # entered is 12345678900, the phone automatically formats it to ((234) 567-8900, skipping the first digit, is this expected SF behavior? Are there any suggested workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

The Phone field in any object is a special type of input field which gets the phone number and format it to the US format.

In your case when you enter a phone number starting with 1, it considers it as US Phone number(US phone numbers have country code as +1) and formats the number (3numeral)3numeral-4numeral format.

To have workaround for this, you need to use apex:inputText and get the Phone number and do your formatting in your controller if any.

Am afraid that you will be out of luck if you just use StandardController.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. Yes, I did the workaround but wanted to confirm if that's the existing behavior and seems like it is.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent automatic formatting use a + at the beginning of a phone number. No reliable way is available to prevent this automatic formatting without custom coding. As an example +12345678900 will remain same way when you leave that field. This is noted in [this](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000181563&language=en_US) documentation. Hope this will help.